# Submit value of a list element

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a dropdown menu, that consists of elements from a db table:

```
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
        Production lines 
        <span class="caret"></span>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        {% for line in lines %}
          <option>{{ line[0] }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </li>
```

I need to make it so that when the user clicks an element, the value of the chosen element is submitted.

Currently I only know how submit something through forms with a submit button. Would appreciate if someone listed out some approaches on how know  to know what the user has chosen or inputed.

Comment: You could add an onselect javascript trigger.

Comment: Also, your example is a bit unclear.  You are presenting the choices as `<option>` tags, but there is no enclosing `<select>` tag.

Comment: @JohnGordon you probably meant <select> tag, but maybe he wants to use <li> tags instead of <option>

Comment: @Kronen fixed.  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @John Gordon recommended, you could use a Javascript `window.onselect` OR `window.onchange` call when the user selects an element.

For example, https://jsfiddle.net/fnpv6cxf/ has the included method from the [Mozilla Developer Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselect) for using `onselect`.

Using `onchange`: https://jsfiddle.net/fnpv6cxf/1/

Comment: isn't onselect for selecting text? I think you meant onchange

Comment: @Kronen correct, I interpreted his request of "when a user clicks an element" to mean text, but it could be an `onchange` event as well.